# Keep public/uploads folder of the last version with capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano, production

I am using Rails 4 with Capistrano to deploy on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and my users are able to upload files which are stored in `/public/uploads`. This folder should always be kept for new versions and should never get files from the git repository.

After reading a few guides I followed those steps:

Adding this to my `deploy.rb`:

```
set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/uploads}
```

Adding this to my `/.gitignore`:

```
# Ignore uploads
/public/uploads
```

Deleting the folder in my current git repository:

```
git rm -r --cached public/uploads
```

Now if I run `cap deploy:setup` I get this error:

```
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.
```

If I define the stage `production` the deploy begins but I aborts very early:

```
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:setup' (see --tasks)
```

And if I use my regular command to deploy `cap production deploy` everything works but the `public/uploads/` folder will be renewed as before those changes.

Not sure if I am just missing the setup command or if I made mistakes in setting this up. My `deploy.rb` looks like this:

```
# Change these
server 'ip', port: port, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:blabla/bla.git'
set :application,     'blub'
set :user,            'blib'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/uploads}
#set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end


namespace :sake do
  desc "Run a task on a remote server."
  # run like: cap staging sake:invoke task="a_certain_task"
  task :invoke do
    on roles(:all) do |h|
      execute "cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current && bundle exec rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}"
    end
  end
end


# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Comment: Is there a `public/uploads` folder in your `shared` directory in production?
Independent of that - you can just put `public/uploads` right in the first `set :linked_dirs` withought the need of setting it twice.

Comment: Oh yes and I think there is the mistake. In production in the `shared` directory is the `public/uploads` folder but in there is another `upload` folder so that the path for the images is `/public/upload/upload` instead of `public/upload`.